# Best approach for historical token balances for each specified wallet

Tags: web3js, blockchain, erc-20, nodejs, ethers.js

I am trying to archieve the following:

- -have a set of wallets
- -have the erc20 token balances for each of these wallets (every token on the chain or at least top 500)
- -data updated as close to realtime as possible

using 3rd party API's like etherscan or ethplorer not working due to rate limiting if the set of addresses is too big. Im talking about 100K+ addresses to be used for this and every erc 20 token on the blockchain.

When I query the balanceOf methods for each wallet against each token contract address, it takes too long time to retrieve data and store it into the database, at it would for example need me to call balanceOf for wallet X against every erc20 token.

Does anyone on here have an idea how to archieve this best?

I want to later on be able to query my database like this:
query difference of address holdings against how it was 1 hour ago, 4 hours ago and so on.

Comment: See [Multicall](https://github.com/joshstevens19/ethereum-multicall) and [The Graph](https://thegraph.com/). For the latter, you would need to look for specific subgraphs that index your tokens, or even build your own subgraph.

Comment: the graph looks interesting but after going through the docs, it seems I would have to create a subgraph for every single erc20 token I want to be checked which is a pain as I have to setup a bunch of config files for each of them.

Comment: Nah, you can simplify that with [data source templates](https://thegraph.com/docs/developer/create-subgraph-hosted#data-source-templates). But anyway, there may already be subgraphs for the tokens that you want to index. I suggest looking for help in their [Discord server](https://discord.gg/vtvv7FP).

Comment: thank you for the tip. Still open to alternative ways of solving this maybe even without 3rd party services like that.

Comment: Unfortunately, the core Ethereum protocol isn't optimized for reading data, it's optimized for syncing the blockchain state in real-time. It's "write efficient" rather than "read efficient", which is why you will likely not be able to make do without a 3rd party service.